# Zend Navigation - setParent Zend_Navigation_Container

Tags: zend-framework, multidimensional-array, zend-navigation

Currently working on some modifications inside a Zend Framework website. One of the things I've been trying to change is the navigation structure and caching of the website. Unfortunate I've came accros a small problem which I, for some reason, cant figure out.

The problem is that I've build up a multi dimensional tree structured array from a database, which I want to pass on to the Zend Navigation class. To me, the array seems legit but Zend throws back the setParent error '*Argument 1 passed to Zend_Navigation_Page::setParent() must be an instance of Zend_Navigation_Container, string given*'.

After some debugging and research, I've found a test array ([pastebin array](http://pastebin.com/4C3nss0P)) and pasted this in as the first argument array. The array looks (as far I can see) almost the same as my generated array ([pastebin array](http://pastebin.com/ftK4DiC9)).

I hope someone can help me move on with this problem.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your array that you are sending to setParent is an instance of Zend_Navigation_Container.

First paste your array through Zend_Navigation() then paste the Instance through the setParent function of Zend_Navigation_Page.

Comment: It's not that I do anything wrong, only thing is that something is wrong with my generated array. How I know this? well, when I pass in the so called 'test array' directly into Zend_Navigation... it works perfectly as I want it to.

There has to be something wrong with array structure of a variable inside one of the children.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Thanks to the 'test array' I've added variables from my generated array one by one. After adding the $row['parent'] variable, the 'test array' also crashed into the setParent error.

```
foreach($elements as $key => $value) {

    $leaf = $value
    $value['swag'] = $value['parent'];

    unset($value['parent']);

}
```

Code above is not the exact code used, just the snippet which fixed this bug.